# Saving a string Android

Tags: java, android, string, save

I'm trying to save a url as a string so that I can use it in another part of my app but its not working properly. Here's what I have.

Saving

```
        String FILENAME = "usertimetable";
        String string = mWebView.getOriginalUrl();

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(string.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Opening

```
        FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput("usertimetable");
        url = fis.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `read()` method, rather than `toString()`.

(http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html for more info.)

Comment: Read seems to be for an int no? Sorry Ill try to work on that...new to this site and I forget...thanks

Comment: You can add a byte array as an argument to the read method to have it store the contents of the file in there. Each byte in the array will, in your case, represent a letter; allowing you to use it further.

Comment: I think the problem is that my code is in two different java files and cannot be referenced?

Comment: If the file is stored in a position that can be accessed publicly then in shouldn't matter. toString() will definitely not work, though, as it represents the object rather than what it does with a file. Anyway, time for me to get some sleep. Good luck. : )